# SQL Server Deny all users from a table except for one user

Tags: sql-server, permissions, database-permissions

Im not too familiar with SQL Server. Can one of you experts please help me with this !

Ive got a table where I want to stop everyone from making changes (Select is fine) except for one user who can read and write to it.

So far Ive got the following to give the user access,

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON [dbo].[RAckNakLog] TO [svc-eR]
```

How do I stop everyone else from writing to it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just the opposite:

```
DENY INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON [dbo].[RAckNakLog] TO [svc-eR]
```

If you already granted access to a user you need to `revoke` them (like *delete* `GRANT` or `DENY`)

```
REVOKE INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON [dbo].[RAckNakLog] TO [svc-eR]
```

Comment: Yeah but thats not what im after. I want to deny all other users from modifying the table. And only user svc-eR to have write access.

Comment: So you need to create a new `ROLE` in the database, `DENY` access to that table and then add all users to the `ROLE`. you'll still will need to add each new user to the role when creating them.